# Dovetail two blocks of bits

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, binary

Check if two blocks of bits dovetail perfectly.

## Specifications

- A block of bits is a fixed sequence of 8 bits just like this for example : **11110101**.
- For simplicity we refer to `truthy`/`falsey` values as `1`/`0` bits but they can be everything capable of representing those two states in a clear, well defined and consistent way, for example :`0/1` `x/y` `False/True` `"false"/"true"` `'a'/'b'` `[]/[...]` `odd/even` `>0 / <0`  `0 / !0`

**What does it mean dovetail perfectly?**

- 1's bits of one block can fit only into 0's of the other block or outside it.
- You can shift an entire block left or right but you cannot modify a block nor reverse it.
- The resulting block must contain all 1's of both inputted blocks and only those.
- There must not be any 0's between 1's while there can be any trailing and leading 0's.
- The resulting block can be more than 8 bits long.
- Example

```
 Input : [ 10010111, 01011010 ]
 
             10010111 
             ↓  ↓ ↓↓↓
           01011010   <- shif by 2
  result   0111111111  => dovetails perfectly
```

**Input:** two blocks of bits.

- You don't need to handle empty blocks (all 0's).

**Output:** your solution have to clearly state if input blocks can dovetail perfectly as described above or not.

- the resulting block won't be a valid answer.

## Test cases.

```
00000000, 00000000 | you don't  
00000000, ...      | need to
...     , 00000000 | handle these

11111111, 11111111 -> True
11111111, 10000000 -> True
11110000, 00101000 -> False 
00101000, 10100000 -> True
10000000, 00111000 -> True
00110011, 11001100 -> True
00010000, 11101010 -> False
10000100, 10111101 -> True 
01111010, 01011111 -> True 
10010101, 00001101 -> False 
01010011, 10110000 -> True
00000111, 00010011 -> False
00000011, 00000101 -> False
```

## Rules

- Input/output can be given by [any convenient method](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- You can print it to STDOUT, return it as a function result or error message/s.
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

---

[Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19178/84844)

Comment: I take it we also can't reverse a block? Might be worth saying explicitly.

Comment: Can we take the inputs as 8-bit numbers from 0 to 255?

Comment: @xnor yes we can't reverse, initially I was adding this specific but I decided to remove it. I think 8 bit numbers is fine as input and also more than 8 bits depending on the language, I didn't specified and left this opportunity to default I/O rules

Comment: @Arnauld The test cases seem to say we don't have to handle any all-zero inputs.

Comment: @xnor Ah ... the famous 'put some part of the spec in the test cases' joke. :-) Thank you, I totally missed that.

Comment: @Arnauld true ahahah! Actually it was specified initially,  but I missed it during the many reviews on sandbox

Comment: That's better now. :-)

Comment: @xnor now forbidden reverse is now specified, thanks

Comment: Is it intentional that you say `1`/`0` as one of the "normal" ways to represent bits, but `0`/1` as one of the other options?  i.e. you can take your inputs bitwise inverted as binary integers, like a C caller could pass `foo(0, 0)` to give inputs that represent 8 set bits in each input.

Comment: @Peter Cordes `0` and `1` are just two different symbols in the end.. There could be a civilization which uses `1` `0` instead, and counts backwards.. So yes for me it's fine to use inverted integers, in that case you have to dovetail 0's.

Comment: That's what I thought, and agreed it's reasonable, but I wondered if you might have just switched conventions because everything else was listed with that order, too, like `"false"/"true"` which would be surprising because it's strings as well as inverted from our normal conventions of what those words mean.

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>63 54 52</s>  50 bytes

<sup>*Saved 2 bytes by applying an optimization similar to the one suggested by @AZTECCO on my C answer*</sup>

Expects `(a)(b)`, where **a** and **b** are bytes. Returns **0** if the blocks can dovetail perfectly or **1** otherwise.

```javascript
a=>g=b=>b?a<<8&b|(c=a<<8|b,c+=c&-c)&c-1&&g(b<<1):1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZHBDsIgDIbvPsVOZETn6M2YMW8@gS8AyBbNMsymnvbuKHTDJS6shKQkX3/@tnfxFr3qbo9n1pqrthW3gpc1l7yUJ1EUByKHVHGXDXKntlyRTFGiMiCkTmVRAD2CVabtTaP3janTKmUSxqDznCZ5nly6l95EcYaxgnvkmzMGDAJ@Fk2vk7@CAHl9WNWfLGApQBx3iLvYLL6iOAvunbY7M/fLbiCY9yU/@YVmEUH3WBDlAacD2K23D/Fp@hFO2xpXET6wHw)

#### How?

The recursive function **g** attempts to shift **b** to the left, 1 position at a time, until the following conditions are both met:

- `(a << 8) & b` is equal to **0**, i.e. **a << 8** and **b** have no set bits in common
- `c = (a << 8) | b` is a sequence of consecutive **1**'s, possibly followed by trailing **0**'s

For the second test, we add to **c** the rightmost set bit in **c** and see if this results in a single **1**, by carry propagation along the sequence of consecutive **1**'s.

We use the following bitwise tricks:

```javascript
c & -c      // returns the rightmost set bit in c

c & (c - 1) // returns c without the rightmost set bit in c
            // (0 if c is an exact power of 2)
```

Example:

```
0111111000 + (0111111000 & -0111111000) = 0111111000 + 0000001000 = 1000000000
1000000000 & (1000000000 - 1) = 1000000000 & 0111111111 = 0
```

We stop the recursion when `b = 0`, which means that all bits have been thrown away. (This is why we do `b << 1` instead of `b * 2`, so that **b** is forced to a 32-bit integer rather than an IEEE 754 floating-point number.)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 68 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:any(a<<8&b<<x==('01'in bin(a<<8^b<<x))for x in range(17))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY9Bb4MwDIXv/AqfBpHYlGyHTQh6a6@77DhtStZQ0CigABr8eubYQGkk5PA@@/mlnfqiqV/mPPucK301Zw06Nomup0in6duDSdMxy6JQqrCswZQ1yV9eFiJvHIyAutP1xUbqVYj5rygrCx9usEkA0LvJF0BTMDF8x@Agw4l26CPx1LVViXVrAD6@oY90/Cxiuhm8UU/r/G@OyCAKu6IZqjMYG6Kt77Djj217OL6fjs41LgHjrP6d1XJguzweKGFwI5LPHSFBSiXVQk666iwEm8RlP7XaYItSe@IF/wGXO8IuPh0Zb5vYTvEiousQZmABNzHbIcX5FND0MrVGp8j04OV9uxgUGniluk0xkozIe0P/)

The function tries all overlap configurations of the two binary sequences. It performs a bitwise `xor` for each configuration and checks if all the resulting `1`s are consecutive. This gives a false positive for some cases where the `xor` operation results in a leading `0`, so additionally it checks if the bitwise `and` operation yields `0`.

-4 bytes thanks to xnor

Comment: Did you mean `...<1>...`?

Comment: @xnor I did not. In many cases, there are trailing zeroes in the binary representation. The `2>...` part captures both with and without trailing zeroes. For the `...<2` part, it does not matter. Any overlapping bits happen at the 8th bit or further left.

Comment: Oh, I see, that's neat. Would it also work to count `'01'` and check that this is `0` using `1>`, for the same byte count? If so, there's probably something shorter with `'01'in`.

Comment: @xnor Good point! That saves some bytes right away.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>78</s> <s>59</s> 57 bytes

Output is via exit code. The program fails (1) for truthy inputs and completes (0) for falsely ones. Input are two non-negative integers.

This is now quite similar to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)'s answers, but I found the `d&-d` trick on [this website](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/position-of-rightmost-set-bit/).

```python
a,b=input()
b<<=8
exec"d=a|b;a&b<1>d&(d&-d)+d>q;a*=2;"*17
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY9NbsMgEIX3nGKUhZ2/Skw2rWKTXbLtphcAgxQrke0SoiZS7@52GIyrgixmHt@8h4dnOPfdbmx660BBWZaj3hrVdsM9LFfC1LV6E@7hmoVV@ttUujA1HmyxtMWLXW3s4bPSa7WrFmt8HX@nhfg6t1cHH/7u9gIg@CcdAOQBlBK7wbddgJO@3qh3j8YNAY7vp6P3vecB452@5Mv9nzHyHqXBtLYw1@KfLHklmUqSpUSJLE8l05jpNJhonGmkjyO5i7LM3sTSnkwwe8cborlib9aR6TjJkdGbaTlHSv4HjozvSnREJllmOVoKSvoB)

Comment: Out of curiosity: where does the `q` come from in your code?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Because chained comparisons are lazily evaluated, q throws a `NameError` if all comparisons before are `True`.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't noticed you throw an error as truthy inputs and not as falsey. That makes sense. And I didn't knew Python comparisons are lazy evaluated like that. If I'd try to use a non-existing variable in Java I would already get an error during compilation way before the program is actually executed. TIL. :) Oh, and nice approach!

Comment: https://catonmat.net/low-level-bit-hacks is a nice explanation of multiple bithacks like `d & -d` to isolate the lowest set bit, with 8-bit examples.  (Like the x86 BMI2 instruction [`blsi`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/blsi).)

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/),  <s>61 58 57</s>  53 bytes

*Saved 4 bytes thanks to @AZTECCO*

A port of my [JS answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211145/58563).

Returns **0** if the blocks can dovetail perfectly or a non-zero integer otherwise.

```c
c;f(a,b){for(a<<=8;b&&a&b|(c=a|b,c+=c&-c)&c-1;b*=2);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZLRboIwFIbvfYqTmSFVGa1xiRlytWQvsF0uMaUUbIatKXW6qK8@VkAJJsvSHQI5NOfr3/@csiBnrApDeFYph1KK7ZYbyLTawNqYbfkUhqWh7EN9cp0Vav/A1CakIXkkZE4Wi3CG8XwxJ4NhyjMhOSRC@gcEryujVjan@mvlDw9oYDcxgoGQRV21k6XIJU@hUDJvPzcEU7I0wNZUw7hEcPwNEBADjmC/FgUHvy0TsFzGQCKbTGKLTiYQwAiPIjiD5manJQibVyzKfDpN0DFT2qeWWUSJ51EvOfkspqdkyiYx8wKGPBaQKBnHMxSdKyENbKg1aKUGYGOr7VLm392n7/JuCplfuyeXQFO4@UUoAtvnN73j7jBuwx1uqlsYY4JJD36hRfkH3ZVfpcl/pK8H7aQJcYbr6vrtOtYuuMK4b7rWrR9H0w1K@qabDRyl2@LOdEsT5441J@061pgmrsNqxtO7J5fJ96XP1TfLCpqXVbD/AQ)

Comment: Bah!  I don't believe it!  After all your help, you had this up your sleeve all along...!

Comment: @Dominic Best man wins - and he **always** has a whopper up his sleeve! :D

Comment: I'll do. Btw glad to see a C answer of you Sir!

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>18</s>  17 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
T_8+Ɱ17;ṢIPʋ€T}1e
```

A dyadic Link accepting two lists of eight ones/zeros which yields `1` if they may dovetail, or `0` if not.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z8k3kL70cZ1hubWD3cu8gw41f2oaU1IrWHq////ow10DKEQxDKIhYggRA1jAQ)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z8k3kL70cZ1hubWD3cu8gw41f2oaU1IrWHq/8PL9YHM//@jo6MNdVBgrI4ChlAslw4OdQbIEKIOxDSEYpAgVJ0hujp0zUB1EK2GcK1I5kGEkNyHJIxuniGqvTATDWHmIQnB7EVWiaTOAN1ehFMg9iIHDIZHDDA9YoCqDskdYLcgeQQuDDMP4WFDZPPgYYZQh3AzmjoDVHVwa2JjYwE) (I reordered them to have the eight truthy cases followed by the five falsey cases).

There is probably a terser way...

#### How?

```
T_8+Ɱ17;ṢIPʋ€T}1e - Link: block A; block B
T                 - truthy indices of A
 _8               - subtract eight from each
     17           - seventeen
   +Ɱ             - map with addition -> a list of the 17 shifted versions of T
            €     - for each:
             T}   -   using the truthy indices of B as the right argument
           ʋ      -   last four links as a dyad:
       ;          -     concatenate
        Ṣ         -     sort
         I        -     incremental differences
          P       -     product (0 if two 1-bits collide; >1 if zero-gaps would result)
               1e - does 1 exist in that result?
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 18 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
¬0*æδì`âε0ζO0ÚPΘ}à
```

Input as a pair of lists of bit-integers, outputs `1`/`0` for truthy/falsey respectively.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0BoDrcPLzm05vCbh8KJzWw3ObfM3ODwr4NyM2sML/v@PjjbUMQBCQzAGwlidaAQPzIqNBQA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/Q2sMtA4vOzzz3JbDaxIOLzq31eDcNn@Dw7MCzs2oPbzgv87/6OhoQx0DIDQEYyCM1YlG8MCsWKBQtKEOCgQKoYvgUmWADFFUwcRANsLsRKhCF4OYZYhhFqr5MLMMsZgF8ynM9UiicFUGKO4yRIQCUkjAbDNEcRdcLdQsJBGou5DVGSKZBbcB6nqEuxBmGaC53gAlBBGuN0CJRwMUfaiqDFBUwd0RGxsLAA). (The test suite contains an additional `Ù`
after the `æ`, otherwise it'll time out. The single TIO takes roughly 35-40 seconds without this uniquify.)

**Explanation:**

```python
¬                # Push the first list of the (implicit) input-pair (without popping)
 0*              # Multiply each value by 0 to create a list of 0s of that same length
   æ             # Get the powerset of this list of 0s (including empty list)
                 # (prefixes builtin would be preferably here, but unfortunately it lacks
                 #  an empty list; obviously this powerset contains a lot of duplicated
                 #  lists, which is why the uniquify `Ù` in the test suite is used to
                 #  make the program faster)
    δ            # Apply double-vectorized (using the powerset of 0s and implicit input)
     ì           #  Prepend the list of 0s to the inner input-list
      `          # Pop and push both list of lists separated to the stack
       â         # Use the cartesian product to get every possible pair of inner lists
        ε        # Map each pair of lists to:
          ζ      #  Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns,
         0       #  using a 0 as trailing filler-item if the lists are unequal in length
           O     #  Sum each inner pair
            0Ú   #  Remove all leading and trailing 0s from this list
              P  #  Take the product of the remaining values
               Θ #  And check that this is equal to 1
        }à       # After the map: check if any are truthy by taking the maximum
                 # (after which this is output implicitly as result)
```

[Try it online for a step-by-step from input to output (with the uniquify to speed it up).](https://tio.run/##dVJNb9QwEL33V4z20l2UaLNXEEKoB8SJio/TaiWcZNKM1o6NPzbdSvwP4IQ4cOII/QHde//SMrajllZCUeIkfm/eezPWTtSEx@Ps9WCCfwqz4uT5zfWLk9kr9OB7hI6s8yCJH7pLf@akjKSG/ALojnTzK9PeWzG4TlsFxHwN4o5auQSsnkxAscVUzugRrcOpPLnHhMPPTJh/GOhToG7/EBVXF5WcQWzj3nDhIBgQQwsqizDceTRlvS/jCjp49s3eajaptEVotDKi4SiLqPg1K55bNDjEmuhwEkq@olytfc/5B7S5C2Xen7c61BLLHTZeW7rCdpFS3P4@TB06syg8Aoqm5@zOEcPBCLJTf1nKj/phvlTi4@HHPz1mKi6vyBTgRmEMpwarR7dstAxqcM9gJDZ4Wp2CcDxEKdGW5FFlN3@q2@vPudq7oLKZFKZUmnWjnQR8kzFvUekdtwBFy0JLbwXJqFilhtyzk9s8Zg787fGkrW5D4/9HOZ/602OzhbEnRuyEDOhA8ITwkucj97DKAb5k8EseT5MI1PHE9wnqbfD9Hmo@KWIbbUZxJS5JcdR5rsxHQgcLFl2QPmLymcjDOnwvjsf1elVUfK3SzdemWN9/pbfN5i8)

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 15 bytes

```
VΠ¤×ż≠ö→kΣQṠ+mṗ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P@zcgkNLDk8/uudR54LD2x61Tco@tzjw4c4F2rkPd07///9/tIEODBqCYCxMxBAmFgsA) or [verify test cases.](https://tio.run/##RY4xCgIxEEX7nGJKxWbmKDaeQVlSiVhrsWAnNtsGFLzBwoJVFtu9w@YicWd@ggNhPv@//GR/OjaZYu9X8Z2ul9TeU/vw/nBexz7vphBfY/f9pFsY@yVopud2HsLGz0OXc5YyVIX7O4wxRwUxC6tyVRCWMgVWRiojegjLHND6lhXglqDHTFf20gNLlDGajAXDpZnxMcfIjLEIDsOxgh8)
Output is a positive integer for truthy cases and 0 for falsy.

### Explanation

Parentheses added for clarity.

```
VΠ¤(×ż≠)(→kΣQ(Ṡ+mṗ))   Implicit inputs: two lists of integers.
  ¤( A )(     B    )   Apply B to both and combine with A.
         →kΣQ(Ṡ+mṗ)    Argument is a list x.
                m      Map
                 ṗ     primality test
              Ṡ+       and concatenate before x.
                       Since 0 and 1 aren't primes, this effectively prepends 8 zeros.
            Q          All contiguous slices.
          k            Classify (into separate lists)
           Σ           by sum.
         →             Get the last class, i.e. the slices with maximal sum.
                       They are those that contain all the 1s of x.
    ×ż≠                Combining function:
    ×                  Cartesian product by
     ż                 zip (preserving overflowing elements) by
      ≠                absolute difference.
                       Now we have a list of all combinations of slices from both extended lists,
                       with 1 and 1 producing 0.
V                      Does any of them have
 Π                     nonzero product (all 1s)?
```

Comment: Nice! I think C answers and some others can benefit how you used  output rules

Answer (score 3):

## x86 32-bit machine code, 27 bytes

An x86-64 version would be callable from C as `int dovetail(dummy, unsigned x, unsigned y);` Returns EAX=0 for dovetail, non-zero for not; all paths of execution for non-zero inputs that don't dovetail lead to `EAX=(x<<n)|y` as the last thing calculated in EAX before returning.   Also more simply and obviously, returns ZF=1 for dovetail, ZF=0 for not.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVPLbtswELzrK/bYonYgAUVgxLeiCVCgp/pSNEgDUlpZjNekSlKWbPTf3V3Kqh8xoIf3MZydWakQcKtpP7cqbI/HJfTObwL0DVrQnaEItfMwLO7n959nHIkQG4StKhtjEUpXIfSGCBq1Q1BV5TGEeTAHhNZjbQYMWVa5HUZl6AHe/5agnSOYSuDD4@rbDB6//vyYSXoomzVA1cygopu@0BBgNcwW/N61LXrQ@4gBlEc4oHfZHTnXPiQYjkdI1YDBpNCbPfD9js/1pNpr5I1pQdk9aBN5RFuTKSPPIVlCxXdUjPTMeJ8Y7uXUhn86s1OEljVy8BdYt99JPevs/HROa@xaYEMC06EWsFJoqSGFQuMn/JJuBzZ1BMcWkOvTiCOKseXY8l7b2HkrE0Sz7lwXUqOczj1MsYCAUf5fjJbIPDPYvHg545Sc89ItOk5NklK2OrHlxuuzyWwQNAU/FZwmfEu6T4a/1q4TjJFug2xerwI4S/szvxlL2EOeTW6NpvK2gdh56WlgaLH9RocNYgsSF/k7loOA9wwakUL2Obo2y244jYcsl@AxycjWdsjCwa@nMTWBF8nk/xtcYcQyGsffzx6@fF/9uCrOUzEOJgqVRHVnVGLDw6bg6ukBzLYlw8ssq5OWWbqZSHZck9OK4DVE5WM2PkY@W7cbVzzXeVHkeZGfw6JSriXI12h3qej83Y2zTuWA@nIlMR7YyOycFTuL0@5FyIdFfvwH).  NASM listing: offset, machine code, source

```
 1                         dovetail:                   ; bool dovetail (ESI, EDX)
 2 00000000 86F2               xchg  dh, dl             ; shl edx,8 ; upper bytes are zero
 3                         .loop:
 4 00000002 85F2               test  edx, esi
 5 00000004 7510               jnz   .overlap           ; skip any bit conflicts
 6                         
 7 00000006 8D0432             lea   eax, [edx+esi]     ; equivalent to | or ^ for non-overlapping bits
 8 00000009 0FBCC8             bsf   ecx, eax           ; count trailing zeros
 9 0000000C D3E8               shr   eax, cl            ; shift out low zeros
10 0000000E 40                 inc   eax                ; turn contiguous low bits into 1 set bit
11                         
12 0000000F 8D48FF             lea  ecx, [eax-1]        ; clear lowest set bit
13 00000012 21C8               and  eax, ecx            ; like blsr  eax, eax
14 00000014 7404               jz   .dovetail_found     ; there was only 1 set bit, now 0
15                         .overlap:
16 00000016 01F6               add  esi, esi
17 00000018 79E8               jns  .loop             ; keep looping until ESI hits the top
18                         
19                         .dovetail_found:
20                             ;; return value in ZF:
21                                   ; 1 for dovetail detection by BLSR
22                                   ; 0 for exiting loop via ESI setting SF: implies non-zero
23 0000001A C3                 ret
```

See https://catonmat.net/low-level-bit-hacks for an overview of bithack tricks including isolating or clearing the lowest set bit.

---

Alternate versions:

BMI1 [`blsr eax, eax`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/blsr) is 5 bytes, same as `lea  edx, [rax-1]` / `and eax, edx`.    That would require BMI1 (Haswell+, Piledriver+).  I used `and` instead of `test` so an integer result in EAX would be available.

BMI1 [`blsi ecx, eax`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/blsi) (5B) / `add eax, ecx` (2B) (`eax += lowest_set_bit(eax)`) turned out *not* to be the shortest way to turn a contiguous bit-range into a single set bit.  Instead, shifting to the bottom with `bsf` / `shr` / `inc` saved 1 byte in 32-bit code, for a total of 6 bytes to turn a contiguous bit-range into a single set bit.  An x86-64 version (no single-byte `inc` encoding) could save instructions at equal code-size by doing that, though, if BMI1 was available.

---

I was hoping to avoid doing the `x & y == 0` test separately from combining the bits.  e.g. by **XORing** them together and checking that a contiguous bit-range started at the bottom of one of the inputs:

```
    mov  eax, edx
    xor  eax, esi
    jz  .all_cancelled      ; exclude all-zeros from the 1-set-bit test

    blsi  ecx, esi          ; isolate lowest set of the shifting input
    add   eax, ecx          ; carry turns contiguous set bits into 1
                    ; BROKEN, need blsi(esi|edx)
```

But we can't just use the lowest set bit of the XOR result; some conflicting bits might have cancelled each other.  e.g. x=0b110010 y=1 would give a false-positive when with `x ^ (y<<1) = 0b110000` having all its set bits contiguous.

And it doesn't work to isolate the lowest set bit of the input you're shifting; once you shift it left past the lowest set bit of the other input, you need to be adding *that* isolated bit instead.  e.g. the following input was mis-handled by my first version using `xor` and `blsi ecx, esi`, because it only dovetails with ESI's lowest bit shifted left past EDX's lowest set bit.

```
mov edx, 0b0110010
mov esi, 0b1001100
```

This way could still work with some kind of `min(blsi(x), blsi(y))`, or `blsi(x|y)`, but doing that separately is not a win.

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), <s>149</s> 139 bytes

```
: d ( a b -- ? ) [ 8 [ 0 suffix ] times 15 rotate ] bi@
all-rotations [ dupd [ + ] 2map [ 0 = ] trim all-equal? ] map
f [ or ] reduce nip ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVBBTsMwELznFXMEIVc2EhJqheCAhHrpBXGqODiJU6w6dnAcKFS8PbiBYMelslZrz87OzrrihTO2f3pcrh7m2AgtLFfykztpdIuNNV0j9QZbYbVQqLl7QSteO6EL0YbbTOyc5S0aK5z7aKzUDotsuZrj3rwJx6Ui7t2QXJli2xJTkVy6tp@jxBk4chCCW5xjjWsfFG1XVXKHZzhZ@zHsCtY47oRHcnmXcaXIAAwe1yi7pvTpwpcva94MEjeHbitrHMjeJle3HvHVrPJ1Y/3DirIrBLRssOj3YMn5wn9YiVl2iksnJ@UGfD9k9hsx9xjfT95T3XTe2M9O6LK/PO4W4zGXJn5HzTGOPbDEb@gIumyi8@M3ZrNEN0wcdwt@p7r0aDea/Hm8W/iloBv3p1yacGnky3P7bw)

Gets the input as arrays of integers.

A naive solution - pads both arrays with 8 additional 0s, then adds each of the rotations of the second array to the first one, trims the leading/trailing zeros and check if the resulting arrays consist only of one number (1).

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>82</s> 81 bytes

```
$'¶$`;
(.+),(.*;.*)
$2,$1
+`;(.)(.*),(.)
-$1$3;$2,
-(0|(1))+
$#2
;|,

m`^0*1+0*$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY47DgIxDER7XwMj8vFG9lLmANwChYKCAgpEuefiAFwsu7azwlLk0czLJO/75/G69WO4tA54@n2xVQglRwol1ZIi4EwokFsNJW6eBhEmFDzXLYIp8BIkxgx4mKEuBPBsV06SOWHvMoZ2AX@HfcxRQczCqmAX5EuZASsjOyN6yJc5TutbVuC3xHvMhLG3HrdEGaPJWGd4NLN/DNgzYyxyh92xghU) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
$'¶$`;
```

Create duplicates of the input with `;`s inserted at every position.

```
(.+),(.*;.*)
$2,$1
```

Swap the two inputs if the `;` lies within the second.

```
+`;(.)(.*),(.)
-$1$3;$2,
```

Try to dovetail the part between the `;` and the `,` with the other input.

```
-(0|(1))+
$#2
```

Count the number of bits in each overlap.

```
;|,
```

Delete the separators.

```
m`^0*1+0*$
```

Check whether a dovetail produced a valid result. Edit: Saved 1 byte by returning any non-zero value for a valid result (value is number of possible dovetailings plus one if concatenating the inputs is a valid dovetailing).

Comment: Yes you can drop it!

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>105</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>63</s></sup> 62 bytes

Saved a whopping 13 bytes thanks to the man himself [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)!!!
Saved a byte thanks to [AZTECCO](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/84844/aztecco)!!!

```c
t;f(a,b){for(a<<=t=8;b&&t;b*=2)t=a|b,t/=t&-t,t=a&b|t&-~t;t=b;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVLbboJAEH33K6YkEtAxchHFrNuXpl9RTbMLS8tD0cA@kCL9dToLaLWRZE5m58ycnT0hWXwkSddpljkCpdtkx9IRux3XPGbStjWTMx64mouzRL3k2l5opJMtz5T@aKa5ZG2XFxq@RF447qSZAH2moFWl38XbATg0QRQhDLDyEEz4QYwQ@ZSsKcLAVAystghxiLBBCFt2ryZv1Pr5XmhNEJFI4K0IQgI/JpGtaSIhf2MuoEJ0I6fqk6q1SntBaMwaCF6P/3Lvgt44nnyKcgblsIq1r1@Dfb19oYgshNtzaNFEP0KugmOuzYtU1TTnsTHdQZV/q2PmXBZyl2Nhdq0wmM/7bhcGdy@PEKQ0utzzB3ZHywstH9KK6KsNjxoqanh6Gn6MeyY5lqVKtBEAzqs/8lQSnTnWNEwRCGDxDNMUptW@IHMEgkSokMwbFQ6jcDtpu18)

Returns \$!0\$ for true and \$0\$ otherwise.

#### Explanation

Shifts the first parameter, \$a\$, over \$8\$-bits so we can try all different shift positions by just shifting the second parameter, \$b\$. Loops over all shifts of \$b\$ checking to see if all bits are ever different from \$a\$ and \$b\$ forms one continuous block of \$1\$s when combined with \$a\$.

Comment: ...I've been frantically fixing my buggy first 'C' attempt, and when I finally post the fix, I see that you've got almost exactly the same strategy...  Now I need to learn how you saved those 3 bytes...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Yeah, basically shifting and making sure the bits are all different but form a block of `1`s when combined. Started dead simple to make sure it worked and then started doing tricks - best way with C. One nice trick is `n & (n - 1)` is zero iff \$n\$ is a power of \$2\$.

Comment: `t/=t&-t` can be used instead of `t>>=__builtin_ctz(t)`

Comment: @Arnauld Now **that's** a nice trick - thanks! :D

Comment: @Arnauld - which I have also now stolen, so thanks from me, too...

Comment: I *love* the trick of ending the loop when ```b``` is completely shifted-out to the left!  I shan't copy it here, but expect to do so in the future...  Really neat!

Comment: @AZTECCO Thanks for reminding me, noticed that but go so into into it forgot. Great challenge - thanks muchly! :D

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 68 bytes

```perl
s/\b0+|0+\b//g;s/(1*)(.*?)(1*) //;y/01/10/;$_=/^(0*$1)?$2(${3}0*)?$/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7BCsIwEETv@YocckgjurOKpyL9kaJQEBGKLdaLqL9u7O6muBBmmH2ZZDzf@33OE7UdVm@s2o7oUk8UOVVxk5pKjCeqnwQmBtXhdKBjRApcNWEbw2v3QZot5cxl/GLcP4GNJmI8wBDnFuNNhCmwMLwwLMebaGK0vKUFdoutR0NXdO6xiIVR2itrDEoz7GMOtlNGV5bAEi34DuPjOtymvO7HHw)

- `s/\b0+|0+\b//g` trims 0 from two blocks
- `s/(1*)(.*?)(1*) //` substitution to remove the first argument, and capture 3 groups :

  - $1: the left ones
  - $2: shortest sequence between
  - $3: the right ones
    (eventually)
- `y/01/10/` transliteration of second argument remaining (bitwise not)
- `/^(0*$1)?$2(${3}0*)?$/` the pattern second argument (inverted) must match

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>94</s> <s>82</s> <s>71</s> 70 bytes

*Edit: -12 bytes by poring over Noodle9's similar C answer and rather shamelessly stealing all of the golfing tricks that I could use here... so please upvote that one, too!*

*More edits: ...thanks to various stolen tips & tricks from Arnauld, also -12 more bytes...*

```c
c;i;f(a,b){for(b<<=9,i=18;i-->1;i*=a&b||c&c++)a*=2,c/=(c=b|a)&-c;i=i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZFbboMwEEW/yyoQUpGdDGpsHgE57kryY1yoLKW0AvIVsnY6g1lAawmbI6R7uB7b7NPadbXKqZ4ZaPmj/x5Ze7noBpwWtXJZ9i6UO2iTtstiU3s8cnPQEuybZla3i@FphnHt1HN1wxx/GTcwHj2iOI5ffkb81LNk7qZZ6NePmEASjN10v81EbB7vHb8OCciy3FbPduJcRQEOIevdgfR3R29u0y4pToAPOjYIqIE5UZHBw/8M14En2yHKCg0eAjqUAuSpQIOHkEGICmROCg8BJUQuQdQNKTyFOKSEptxGQRB0kKLBKqTYIKBEnYM40314CClxBkGDoFdIPAeaAe4h4Qbo17hT@BlF6y8)

My first ever answer in 'C' (which embarassingly didn't work the first time: thanks to Arnauld for spotting the bug...).

Input is two 8-bit integers, outputs '-1' (truthy) if bits of input dovetail together perfectly, '0' (falsy) otherwise.

Works by first bit-shifting b by 9 bits, and then testing for successful dovetailing with a shifted by 1..18 bits (so, all-the-way to the right up to all-the-way to the left).
Tests dovetailing at each position by checking that a AND b is zero (so there are no 'clashing' bits), then taking A XOR B, chopping-off any trailing zeros, and testing whether x AND (x+1) is equal to zero (which is only true for 2^n-1 = strings of 1-bits).

Comment: I also have an [81 byte](https://tio.run/##JcfRCoIwFADQ5/YVJRT3MgONqOBufkkk7k5jYCvmfMn89pX0dg7v78wpMVly1EGTG5y6ZwCjlL6Qk1KVZ8KJq0rXtRldH52vOb6BNTRKObwZJPvRG@AdS4k0E2tLc3I@rh@N84BiEqtX@L2DLLZDLPXWrhccFoR2GPu4CGIYW7z6LD8WeXkq8g7@QCQxC5G@) answer, but it leaves-behind disrupted global variables & so cannot be run multiple times sequentially.  I assume that this is frowned-upon (or outright banned): perhaps someone can confirm/refute this...?

Comment: Regarding your question: [this is indeed banned](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4940/58563)

Comment: Rats!  How did I miss that...

Comment: ...fixed at last

Comment: The `c/=c&-c` trick works fine with Noodle9's answer, but in your case it may result in a division by zero and a floating point exception. (Example: a=9 / b=9.)

Comment: Ouch!  Why wasn't that in my test cases!

Comment: @Arnauld thanks for *another* bug-spot!  Hopefully fixed now...

Comment: Yes, all cases seem to pass fine now. :-)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 29 bytes

```
¬⬤α№⭆↨⁺×Ｘ³χ⍘η³×Ｘ³κ⍘θ³¦³⮌⍘λ²01
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYwxDsIwDEV3TmF1cqQgxXRkAmZQBFwgqiJaYQgkaTl@cMMCLP9b7z@5613sguNSbBzuGQ8h44YZnYZdGAWcsvDL3j1w65JHy2PC83DzCW14@YitBjJKw7x@XOw1tErQn3b9tZ7VUnNqOPrJR3n/tbOGVd0bQ40cal0KGUOGiBa1JMpy4jc) Works by dovetailing in base 3, which avoids issues other answers have when trying to XOR or add the values together. Explanation:

```
  α                             (Uppercase alphabet)
¬⬤                              No indices match
   №                            (Non-zero) Count of
                           01   Literal string `01` in
                   θ            First input
                  ⍘ ³           Converted as if base 3
              ×                 Multiplied by
                ³               Literal 3
               Ｘ                Raised to power
                 κ              Current index
      ⁺                         Plus
            η                   Second input
           ⍘ ³                  Converted as if base 3
       ×                        Multiplied by
         ³                      Literal `3`
        Ｘ                       Raised to power
          χ                     Predefined constant 10
     ↨                ³         Converted to base 3 as a list
    ⭆                           Map over digits
                         λ      Current digit
                        ⍘ ²     Converted to base 2 as a string
                       ⮌        Reversed
                                Implicitly print
```

Comment: What's the difference between true and false outputs? They both appear to be `-` when I run the linked program

Comment: @JoKing There's a byte missing. I'll add it shortly.

Comment: @JoKing Or better still, I can golf it away again...

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>86</s> <s>83</s> 82 bytes

```java
(a,b)->{int i=18,t;for(a<<=8;--i>0;i=(a&b)>-(t&(t&-t)+t)?i:0,b*=2)t=a|b;return i;}
```

Inspired by halve the other answers.
-3 bytes thanks to *@AZTECCO*.
-1 byte thanks to *@ceilingcat*.

Inputs as (32-bit) integers. Output as `-1` for truthy and `0` for falsey.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##dVI9T@QwEO35FSMXyL58yOYatCZLQUVxUFACxSR4F0PwRvFkpRPsb1/8kexdgxXNTJ7fzHuy/YZ7rN5e3o9dj97DH7Tu8wzAOjLjBjsDd/E3AdDxGLGMsRU64IezEDwh2Q7uwEFz5Fi2olp/Ro5t1GVJerMbOV5dNZe6quxaattwPG/FuuJ0Hr6KREHi2q5k2f5qLgQ1@NXq0dA0OrD6cNRRZJjaPojMWvudfYGP4JU/0Gjd9vEZcNx6kb1GwYwDGU836A2sgCkplVRKQUohaDUvWIr/EJlXQmIBqTsiSwE5Rc5Mjhy1cKJcnJzLgGR21JJZXWYMkqsQ9Jxldpj8ZLHgWaY5kSPnyTIb0zLvJU7ayojMSBrAaj/0ljjTTMyHBHA6OuuGiTw0p9Na2MDSLS/3j81teBZbM9Z77Cdzv@G581E@lxeinJlxtT8xVWQuMx/@ejIf9W6ieghWqHf/BhYMOCuwYAJYqFk9msEg8d8VDyATdW/cll65EMVpdO5pQ8/qiVjh6i69xlnvkN7r4fgN)

**Explanation:**

```java
(a,b)->{               // Method with two integer parameters and boolean return-type
  int i=18,            //  Index-integer, starting at 18
      t;               //  Temp-integer, uninitialized
  for(a<<=8;           //  Bit-shift the first input-integer `a` 8 bits to the left
      --i>0            //  Loop `i` in the range (18, 0):
      ;                //    After every iteration:
       i=(a&b)         //     Get `a` bitwise-AND `b`
         <             //     And check that it's smaller than:
          -(           //      The negative of:
            t          //      `t`
             &         //      Bitwise-AND with:
              (t&-t)   //       `t` bitwise-AND `-t`
                    +t)//       and add `t`
         ?             //     If this is truthy:
          0            //      Change `i` to 0 (which will also stop the loop)
         :             //     Else:
          i,           //      Keep `i` the same
       b*=2)           //     And multiply `b` by 2
    t=a|b;             //   Set `t` to `a` bitwise-OR `b`
  return i;}           //  Return `i` as result (where -1 means we've changed `i` to 0
                       //  manually as truthy output and 0 means the loop has fully
                       //  looped as falsey output)
```

Comment: Why don't you use --i>0; and return `i`?

Comment: @AZTECCO The TIO you've linked all returned 0, but you're indeed correct I can save 3 bytes with `-->0`. Thanks!

Comment: Previous link was wrong sorry, this may work.. Not sure though.